# Dynamically render element angular form

Tags: angularjs

Hi I am dynamically adding element based on bootstrap typeahead selected data type. Problem because of always remove html element and adding new. form error collection still hold that previous error and show mulitple error for single html element. Please Help what is wrong here.

```
var addDynamicControl = function (fieldInformation) {

                   if (angular.element("#" + scope.advanceSearchItem.searchItemIndex).length) {
                       angular.element("#" + scope.advanceSearchItem.searchItemIndex).remove();
                       if (ctrl.advanceSearchForm[fieldInformation.SearchCriteriaName])
                           ctrl.advanceSearchForm[fieldInformation.SearchCriteriaName].$setValidity("required", false);
                   }
                   var angularForm = angular.element("#" + scope.formName);
                   var result = angularForm.append(getTemplateByType(fieldInformation));
                   $compile(result)(scope);
               };
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should clear the typeahead before you insert form element. Try below

```
var addDynamicControl = function(fieldInformation) {

    if (angular.element("#" + scope.advanceSearchItem.searchItemIndex).length) {
        angular.element("#" + scope.advanceSearchItem.searchItemIndex).remove();
        if (ctrl.advanceSearchForm[fieldInformation.SearchCriteriaName])
            ctrl.advanceSearchForm[fieldInformation.SearchCriteriaName].$setValidity("required", false);
    }
    $timeout(function() {
        angular.element('.typeahead')
            .typeahead('val', '');
    }, 0);

    var angularForm = angular.element("#" + scope.formName);

    var result = angularForm.append(getTemplateByType(fieldInformation));
    $compile(result)(scope);
};
```